# Reconfigure downloaded firmware in Debian live CD

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, debian, firmware

Is there any way to reconfigure the downloaded firmware in Debian live CD(Whezzy)?It might be possible if you have installed it on a hard disk because you just have to restart the computer while for a live CD you can't restart because all the data would be lost.

Since my hard disk is not detecting in my computer I'm using a live CD but even after I downloaded the package [firmware-linux-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/all/firmware-linux-nonfree/download) under the wireless network menu it shows *device not ready(firmware missing)* .Does anyone know how to configure the downloaded firmware *without restarting the computer*.

Comment: What firmware are we talking about?  I can only assume your asking about the EFI firmware drivers.  Can you confirm?

Comment: @Ramhound:Oh sorry.I was talking about the firmware given in the link or other firmwares like iwlwifi:https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=firmware-iwlwifi